# displaying crystal report with data of wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am new bee in crystal report. I have to call a WCF service which will return some data in entity list, Now i have to bind this data in a report within a asp.net page. I am not able to find how to do it with crystal report. 
All the example i have found, they are using static connection with database. Is there any way to accomplish it.Any kind of suggestion, guide or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call your service
2. Take the returned list from your service and fill it into a `DataSet`
3. Put your `DataSet` into the `Reportdocument` using the `ReportDocument.SetDataSource(yourDataSet)` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226127(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i am using visual studio 2012 with .net frame work 4.5, how to display a ReportDocument to a ReportViewer

Comment: The method should be the same, not much changed in CrystalReoprts. The reason that the link just mentions VS2005 is that CrystalReports was delivered *with* VS2005 (in the VisualStudio setup files), since VS2008 you have to get it yourself from  SAP (download etc) and install it.

Comment: I have installed the SAP business object, there is no problem with dlls and all. I am using it in asp.net and there is ReportViewer not ReportDocument and the method you have suggested is not present

Comment: You need the right namespace / references. CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll) (From the link above)

Comment: i have both the DLLs added `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` and `CrystalDecisions.Shared` in project and the same i have added with using namespace